# Why is my saveAsync method always returning the same result? (Office.js - Outlook Add-in)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently writing some code as part of an Outlook add-in with the office-js library.

Basically, after clicking a "send" button, my application should save the currently open message as a draft, and then make a call to the Microsoft Graph API, which can send the message.

My code currently looks something like this on the client side:

```
    Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
        async function callback(result) {
            if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                const messageId = result.value

                await axios.post("/api/send", {
                    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken },
                    data: {
                        messageId
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log(result.error)
            }
        }
    );
```

And then, on my server, I'm making this call to the Graph API:

```
    const graphData = await fetch(
        `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/${messageId}/send`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + graphToken,
                'Content-Length': '0'
            }
        }
    );
```

This was all working fine until today. However, I'm now seeing that, no matter which message I press send on, I keep seeing the same message ID from my call to `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()`:

```
// console.log(messageId)
AAMkAGE4ZWVlNjI1LTk3NjAtNDFmYy1hZDhkLTU3ZWY0ZjJiMDk5YgBGAAAAAACghEgqiSFAQo8v+Kh2wPqEBwDoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAAAAEPAADoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAT/OkjAAA=
```

I'm then getting an "Unsupported segment type." error back from Microsoft Graph, which I assume is because the message ID doesn't really exist.

I'm not sure how this could be happening, but I think that it might have something to do with the account that I'm currently developing on. Until yesterday, I was on a free trial of MS Office, which expired. I restarted my subscription again today, but this bug is still popping up.

However, even before today, I was getting unpredictable behaviour with this pattern. Sometimes, the email wouldn't send on the first try, with no apparent errors, and other times, the email would send, but the email wouldn't disappear, leaving a hanging draft in front of the user.

I'd love to hear any help or suggestions on this, because this has been causing a fair amount of frustration!

Comment: Are you converting the EWS ID to a REST ID before invoking MS Graph API to send the message? Take a look at Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox?view=office-js

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to send an eamil using the MS Graph API.

I have tried to reproduce your problem. However I couldn't get the error message like yours.

And I reviewed your description, I have find some issue on your MessageID,

`AAMkAGE4ZWVlNjI1LTk3NjAtNDFmYy1hZDhkLTU3ZWY0ZjJiMDk5YgBGAAAAAACghEgqiSFAQo8v+Kh2wPqEBwDoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAAAAEPAADoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAT/OkjAAA=`

We can find that there is a `/` character in this MessageID. I think we should check how the MessageID is generated.

Comment: The messageID variable here is coming from the `saveAsync()` function. That function is meant to return the ID of the draft that was just saved, but instead I'm getting this same string each time.

Comment: Strange - I just tried again today, and it looks like the ID is slightly different:

`AAMkAGE4ZWVlNjI1LTk3NjAtNDFmYy1hZDhkLTU3ZWY0ZjJiMDk5YgBGAAAAAACghEgqiSFAQo8v+Kh2wPqEBwDoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAAAAEPAADoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAT/OknAAA=`

Comment: It seems like, with the string after the `/`, the character before AAA actually increments by 1 with every new draft that gets made

Comment: Please make sure how do you get the message ID.